# Decompress | Invalid Syntax | Python

Tags: python, base64, zlib, compression

I am trying to decode a large encoded/ compressed file using zlib but it is throwing SyntaxError: Invalid syntax

```
import zlib
import marshal
import new
import sys
import base64
import time
import tty
import termios

a0_func = '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'

with open('compress.txt','r') as f:
    compressed = f.read()

x = marshal.loads(base64.b64decode(a0_func))
x_func = new.function(x, {'ord':ord, 'sys':sys,
                  'map':map, 'chr':chr,
                  'time':time, 'tty':tty,
                  'termios':termios,
                  'len':len,
})
x = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(compressed))
exec x
```

compress.txt is around 2mb in size. I am getting the below error when executed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "decode.py", line 25, in <module>
    exec x
  File "<string>", line 16

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am very novice to this and any leads will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The `exec` statement is used for dynamic execution of Python code. What does it do in your example?

Comment: zlib is not throwing an error. `exec` is. Look at `x` to see why. This has nothing to do with zlib.

Comment: You mean the problem lies in the compress.txt? could you suggest any methods?

Comment: Just. Look. At. x.

Comment: Put x into the bracket.

Comment: @Krishna468 What exactly is the input for this function?